# How could other breakers have been switched off when one was tripped by a short?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

is it possible if one breaker trips, the rest (or some) of the other breakers in the panel will also trip at the same time?

we had put in a separate breaker for the bedrooms, once we connected this to the panel and switch it on, the breaker for this tripped.  We figured out and fixed what the issue was.  When we went back to the panel to reconnect, we noticed that the rest of breakers were off.

I'm trying to figure out how the rest of the breakers on the panel were turned off it was never touched.  is it possible that when that one breaker trip, this also made the rest of the breakers trip?

this maybe an obvious answer to some - sorry, i need some advice as the electrician that was helping me said it is not possible. He said that when one breaker trip, this does not affect the rest of the breakers to turn off as well.  But to me, it is the only rational explanation.

Comment: The rest of the breakers, as in *every other breaker in the entire panel*?

Comment: Depending on the type of panel 1 additional breaker could trip if it were a split buss. but tripping all the breakers could only happen if a newer AFCI in all positions and the new wiring was not correct so it could cause them to think there was an arc fault.

Comment: And were the breakers tripped, or were they switched off? Those are two different states. Methinks you had someone either playing tricks or trying to keep you safe.

Comment: @isherwood - all (five) breakers on the bottom (i have my panel placed horizontally).  the top breakers were fine.

Comment: @isherwood - myself and the electrician were both up in the main floor.  there was no one else in the house to switched off.  The panel was in the basement.

Comment: Arc-fault breakers have little reset buttons on them. Do yours? I don't think you answered my question about breaker state. Tripped or actually off?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't yet turned them back on for some reason, it's most likely just an oopsie. There's what I call Face-Plate panel covers that don't recess or lock themselves around the breaker block nor have any lip that seats around the panel box (dumbest things ever). I & many others have been caught off-guard by these swinging or just shifting enough during removal to shut-off a whole side of the panel. You really don't notice the simultaneous click if you bang the cover or are talking. Maybe you or he hit them with your elbow, but circuits don't just suddenly crave attention.